# concatenate DropDownList id in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm tring to concatenate dropDownList id in jQuery.

This is the DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MyDropdownlist3" Style="display: block" disabled="true" runat="server" Height="23px" Width="200px"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="MyDropdownlist4" Style="display: none" runat="server" Height="23px" Width="200px"></asp:DropDownList>
```

This line of code works for me:

```
$("#MyDropdownlist3").attr("disabled", false);
```

And I have problem when I tried to do this:

```
$("#MyDropDownList" + x).attr("disabled", false);
$('#MyDropDownList' + 3).attr("disabled", false);
```

also this not working (hope it's the same issue).

```
document.getElementById("MyDropDownList" + x).style.display = "Block";
document.getElementById("MyDropDownList" + 4).style.display = "Block"
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: check case of L.... it should be "MyDropDownlist" not "MyDropDownList"

Comment: Have you tried `.prop( "disabled", true );`? Also there is a typo. small letter l and capital L.

Comment: `$("#MyDropDownList" + x).prop("disabled", false).show()` make sure to spell correctly

Comment: You have specified `runat="server"` on your controls, so WebForms will be dynamically changing the `id` of the elements at runtime. You need to use the `ClientId` property to know what it's been changed to.

Comment: @PrashantShirke Sometimes when you focus on code you forget to check out the little things ... THANKS!! it works for me now.

Comment: Yeah, it happens! Welcome :-)